# ZSH custom completion from command output

Tags: osx, zsh, autocomplete

I am creating a custom completion for my command `ipadd` which will automatically complete all the network devices for `OS X`. It has a parameter `--device` which allows you to specify the network devices on the system.

The command to list the network devices in `OS X` is

`networksetup -listallnetworkservices`

The output for it is;

```
An asterisk (*) denotes that a network service is disabled.
Ethernet
Wi-Fi
```

However the first line of the command isn't the network interface and I have modified that command about so that it only shows `Ethernet` and `Wi-Fi`

```
networksetup -listallnetworkservices | sed -n '2,$p'
```

The output for this is;

```
Ethernet
Wi-Fi
```

My question is how can I store that command and use it for auto completion for my `ipadd` command. I know that you can use the `_files` but that is for completing files within the system.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a file named `_ipadd` and put the following in it:

   ```bsh
   #compdef ipadd

   # The line above declares this function as providing completions to 
   # `ipadd`. In addition, it's important that the file name starts with 
   # an `_`, otherwise `compinit` won't autoload it.

   local output=$(networksetup -listallnetworkservices)

   # Split the output on newlines.
   local -a services=( ${(f)output} )

   # Offer the second to the last line as completions.
   _arguments "*:network service:( ${services[2,-1]} )"
   ```
2. Make sure the folder that contains this file is in your `$fpath`. So, if we suppose it's located in `~/func`, then you can do something like this in your `.zshrc` file:

   ```bsh
   fpath+=( ~/func )
   ```
3. Make sure you call `compinit` in your `~/.zshrc` file *after* adding the dir to your `$fpath`. Otherwise, it will not be used for completions.

   ```bsh
   autoload -Uz compinit && compinit
   ```